# Is the following function $f(x)$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I have a problem with this question: 
How can I prove that the following function is continuous, if it is?
$$f(x)=\frac{ \left( \frac{\cos(\cos(\cos \left(\cos(\cos(x))))\right)}{\sin\left(\sin\left(\sin\left(e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^x}}}}}}}}}}}\right)\right)\right)} \right) }{\ln\left(2x+1\right)+2+\cos x}$$

Comment: Continuous on what domain?

Comment: Are those a finite number of cos, sin, and powers of e?  If so composite functions of continuous functions are continuous (where they are defined).

Comment: Notice that it isn't defined for $\ln(2x+1)+2+\cos(x)=0$ (corresponding to $x\approx-.47222$), so it definitely isn't continuous everywhere. Do you have a more restrictive domain?

Comment: The domain is $\left(-\infty \:,\:\infty \:\right)$

Comment: It's not continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ since the denominator is undefined for $x \lte -\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is not continuous at the following points (as it is not defined): When $\ln(2x+1)+2+\cos(x)=0$ (which occurs at $\approx x=-.47223$), and whenever $e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^{e^x}}}}}}}}}}}=k\pi$ for $k$ a positive integer. As well, $\ln(2x+1)$ is undefined for $x\leq-.5$, so the function in question is as well. Otherwise, the function is defined, and is a composition of continuous functions, and hence is continuous.

Comment: And what is the function when $x=-1$? ;)

Comment: You also need the stipulation that $x > -1/2$. Otherwise $\ln (2x + 1)$ is undefined.

Comment: @AJY Good point. I have edited to include that.

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. Observe that $$\lim_{x \to -\frac 12^+} \ln (2x+1)+2 +\cos x = - \infty$$
and also
$$\ln (2x+1)+2 +\cos x \ \bigg |_{x = \frac \pi 2} = \ln (\pi +1) +2 >0$$

So, by Intermediate Value Theorem, there is a point $x_0 \in (- \frac 12, \frac \pi 2 )$ such that $$\ln (2x+1)+2 +\cos x \ \bigg |_{x = x_0} = 0$$

Thus, the denominator is zero at $x_0$ and therefore $f$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

This function is continuous on its domain.  (Just what it's domain is, is a more delicate question.)

- The cosine, sine, logarithm, constant, and exponential functions are continuous.
- Sums, quotients, and products of continuous functions are continuous.
- Compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

All three bullet points above require proof.  All three are standard results.  Once established, these three are enough to deal with this proposed function.